# Beginner - Why do voltage/current behave this way

Tags: voltage, resistors, falstad

I was checking falstad and came around this resistor circuit which lost me completely :

[image]

Knowing that input voltage is 5v and current is 17mA :

1- Why is the voltage 0 after the 200Ohm resistor knowing that It's 3.4V before It ?

2- Why is the current flowing without voltage ? ([here is the animation for those interested](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/)

3- When the current arrives at the first junction, 15mA take the first route, and 2mA take the 2nd route, why is that ?

4- Check this 2nd circuit :

[image]

Why closing the right bottom switch drops the voltage to 0 after the 100/400/800 resistors ?

Comment: 1. Because it's tied to ground. 2. Why not? Does not violate any laws. 3. To minimize the energy loss. 4. Again, tied to ground.

Comment: the voltage-meter needs a reference point; we often call that "GROUND" and define that voltage to be zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The voltage is zero after the resistor because you have defined it to be zero -- it is the circuit common (or ground).
2. If you are talking about the RLC circuit on the front page, it is because the L and C are energy storage elements that are charged by the voltage source before the start of the simulation. The simulation begins at the opening of the switch.
3. It is a parallel circuit. The current is inversely proportional to the resistance/impedance of each branch.
4. The lower right switch is shorting out the 200 ohm resistor, making the voltage difference across it zero.